# Why doesn't GHC resolve this type family instance?

Tags: haskell, type-families, data-kinds

In the following code, GHC is unable to match `Obj Hask` with `*`, despite the declaration that `type instance Obj Hask = *` just above.

What's preventing this?

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

module Minimal where

type family Obj t :: *

type family Arr t :: Obj t -> Obj t -> *

data Hask

type instance Obj Hask = *

type instance Arr Hask = (->)

-- Minimal.hs:15:26: error:
--     • Couldn't match kind ‘Obj Hask’ with ‘*’
--       Expected kind ‘Obj Hask -> Obj Hask -> *’,
--         but ‘(->)’ has kind ‘* -> * -> *’
--     • In the type ‘(->)’
--       In the type instance declaration for ‘Arr’
--    |
-- 15 | type instance Arr Hask = (->)
--    |                          ^^^^
```

It's able to note the equivalence if I give it a nudge

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneKindSignatures #-}
-- …
type Function :: Obj Hask -> Obj Hask -> *
type Function = (->)

type instance Arr Hask = Function
-- compiles just fine
```

Comment: This also works if we write `type Function :: * -> * -> *`. It looks as a bug to me. I wonder if the magic handling of `(->)` during type/kind inference is the culprit.

Comment: Even `type T = (->) ; type instance Arr Hask = T` works. Even `type instance Arr Hask = Id (->)` works (where `Id` is the identity polykinded type family). This has to be a bug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the one spot where type families surprisingly don't "just work".

GHC internally splits declarations into groups and can't use a `type instance` to typecheck things in its own group. Adding intermediate declarations affects this grouping, which is why things may or may not typecheck depending on that.

Another more reliable way to break groups is to add empty Template Haskell splices (`$(return [])` or [`newDeclarationGroup`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/template-haskell-2.19.0.0/docs/Language-Haskell-TH.html#v:newDeclarationGroup)).

See also GHC issues [#22257](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/issues/22257) and [#12088](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/issues/12088).

Comment: Yup, adding `$(return [])` between `type instance Obj Hask = *` and `type instance Arr Hask = (->)` worked.